# Karate: Replacing multiple key values

Tags: karate

I have the following response and i am trying to replace a part if icon-url i.e replace test.com to prod.com.

```
[
  {
    "_": {
      "name": "FA",
      "icon-url": "https://test.com/static/images/air/partner.png"
    },
    "@": {
      "code": "00"
    }
  },
  {
    "_": {
      "name": "DA",
      "icon-url": "https://test.com/static/images/air/partner.png"
    },
    "@": {
      "code": "0D"
    }
  },
  {
    "_": {
      "name": "JC",
      "icon-url": "https://test.com/static/images/air/partner.png"
    },
    "@": {
      "code": "0J"
    }
  },
  {
    "_": {
      "name": "AG",
      "icon-url": "https://test.com/static/images/air/partner.png"
    },
    "@": {
      "code": "1A"
    }
  },
  {
    "_": {
      "name": "AI",
      "icon-url": "https://test.com/static/images/airline/partner.png"
    },
    "@": {
      "code": "1B"
    }
  }]
```

I tried with the following function but this isnt working:

```
* def iconurl = 'prod.com'

* def replaceEnv = function(x){ if (x['icon-url']) x['icon-url'] = x['icon-url'].replace('test.com', iconurl); return x }

* def convertedExpectation = karate.map(result, replaceEnv) // result refers to the response above
```

Please have a look at the code and guide me what is wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, note that `x._['icon-url']` is the same as `x['_']['icon-url']`

```
* def fun = function(x){ var temp = x._['icon-url']; x._['icon-url'] = temp.replace('test.com', 'prod.com'); return x }
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! Just one more clarification please. I forgot to mention. that i have a variable * def env. and want to put an if condition depending on the env. If you suggest, i can ask a new question.

Comment: @user1873274 new questions please